# java LinkedListNode constructor

Tags: java, constructor

When I look the CC150, in one question, the code came like this:

```
LinkedListNode result = new LinkedListNode(carry,null,null);
```

then I search through google but cannot find out what it mean when saying

```
LinkedListNode(carry, null, null);
```

Hope some one can answer my question.

Comment: What exactly is your  question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most standard system would be:

`LinkedListNode(previous, value, next)`

By calling

`LinkedListNode(carry, null, null)`

You are merely not specifying the `value` object and the `next` node. They will be initialized later on.

This is not guaranteed though. The best way to tell is to look at the actual source. The variable names, if done informatively, will tell you exactly what they mean.

For example: [LinkedList#Node](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Node)

Answer (score 0):

A linked list node has at least 2 attributes, the data contained in the node, and the reference to the next node in the list. So a constructor may be called with

```
LinkedListNode node = new LinkedListNode(5, null);
```

The above node contains data 5, and the next node reference is null. A linked list node can have 3 attributes, where the third one is a reference to the previous node in the list. In this case the list is called a double linked list. The constructor can be called with

```
LinkedListNode node = new LinkedListNode(5, null, null);
```

Same as the first example, but now there's a null reference to the previous node. Of course, it all depends on how you define your constructors.